# Is possible to map int to string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns, one of type `INT` and one `NVARCHAR`. I want to map the `INT` to a string according to its value and concat both.

For example:

```
ID    color
-----------------
13    BLUE
13    WHITE
26    YELLOW
35    RED
```

Expected result:

```
BLUE CAR
WHITE CAR
YELLOW HOUSE
RED HAT
```

Using the mapping:

```
13 = CAR
26 = HOUSE
35 = HAT
```

Is this possible? I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please explain do you have a table with mapping fields and IDs? and another table which contains the data (CAR, HOUSE ...)

Comment: I do not have the table with data, only the (ID/color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case` expression :

```
select color + ' ' + 
       (case id when 13 then 'car' when 26 then 'house' when 35 then 'hat' end)
from table t;
```

If you have a mapping table then do `JOIN`:

```
select t.color + ' ' + m.mappingname
from table t inner join
     mapping m
     on m.id = t.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I might go for a derived table and `join`:

```
select t.color + ' ' + v.what
from t join
     (values (13, 'CAR'), (26, 'HOUSE'), (35, 'HAT')
     ) v(id, what)
     on t.id = v.id;
```